# iperf server on windows using python

Tags: python, windows, iperf, iperf3

This may not necessarily be a Python related issue but I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

I'm trying to start an iperf3 server on a Windows system using Python. In my code I have

```
import subprocess
iperfserver = subprocess.Popen(['C:\iperf-3.1.3-win64\iperf3', '-s'])
```

I have also tried

```
iperfserver = subprocess.Popen(['C:\iperf-3.1.3-win64\iperf3', '-s', '-B', '192.168.1.141', '-p', '5201'])
```

On the client side, I start iperf with

```
iperf3 -c 192.168.1.141
```

but I get the message

> iperf3: error - control socket has closed unexpectedly

Everything runs fine if I run iperf3 -s manually in a command prompt.

Comment: Can you check if port is open on host machine and firewall isn't blocking it ?